# Cordova Camera + FlashOn

Tags: cordova, camera, android-camera-intent

Pulling my hair out!

Everytime a camera is opened within my app, I would like to make sure that the flash is on by default. However, standard plugins don't offer such configuration :(

How could I achieve this requirement? I am open to any suggestions, including customizations. I am interested mainly in Android at the moment

Thanks!

Comment: You can switch on the camera light with this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-flashlight

Comment: "you'll want to make sure the torch is switched off when the app is exited via the backbutton. Otherwise, the camera may be locked so it can't be used by other apps" - doesnt seem to be a valid option :(

Comment: Ah, sorry for wrong answer.